# isoPower Input-to-output dipole emissions

Tags: dipole

In ADI's Application Note: [Recommendations for Control of Radiated Emissions with isopower Devices](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-0971.pdf). Section "Input-to-output dipole emissions", it says:

> Input-to-output dipole radiation is generated by driving a current
>   source across a gap between ground planes. This is the predominant
>   mechanism for radiation for isoPower applications. Isolated power
>   supplies, by their very nature, drive energy across gaps in ground
>   planes. The inability of high frequency image charges associated with
>   the power signal to cross the boundary causes differential signals
>   across the gap driving the dipole.

In its isoPower chips, such as ADuM5000, the main "barrier" is transformers. So ideally, there will no current flow from primary side to secondary. So this don't agree with the first words: **"Input-to-output dipole radiation is generated by driving a current source across a gap between ground planes."** . But the following words are interesting,  **"Isolated power supplies, by their very nature, drive energy across gaps in ground planes"**. I don't understand it well, does it mean the energy transfer using transformer will generate "dipole emission" if there is no current flowing across the gap?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Input-to-output dipole radiation is generated by driving a current source across a gap between ground planes"

So, you have 2 transformers that are placed across the isolation gap(literally above that gap). Usually whenever you have some sort of signal(current), its mirror image (that is usually on the ground wire/plane) will follow this signal. When this signal gets to the isolation gap, there is no path available for the mirror image, it will try to couple on to the other side, and that is what essentially causing the dipole emission. And this is why you're recommended to use stitching cap.

"Isolated power supplies, by their very nature, drive energy across gaps in ground planes"
No, if they are switched off, there will be no emissions. What they mean is that isolated power supplies are literally made to drive energy across gaps in ground plane.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder where the "sort of signal (current)" from. Ideally, the signal current flow into one end of the transformer, and flow out of the transformer at the other end. The "energy" is transferred by "magnetic filed". Do you mean the "common mode" part of the signal? But this part has no relation with "energy" transferred to the second side.